# IE8 not displaying ONE image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

This is driving me crazy.  I'm working on a site, every other browser displays this image, including IE6, 7 and 9.  But in IE8 disregards this image completely.  Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?  I pumped the z-index up but that doesn't seem to help.

HTML

```
<div id="building">
    <img src="images/someimg.png" alt="some title" height="110" width="626" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#building {
float: left;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10000;
margin-left: 384px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle showing the issue?

Comment: z-index: 10000;
margin-left: 384px; magic numbers.... agrrr

Comment: JSFiddle or link to the site please!

Comment: www.wmtr.com/newwebsite/en.index.html

Comment: It could be possible that it's not displaying a .png but it is showing .png in other places so that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ben : I cannot replicate the problem, it seems ok from here

Comment: @PranavKapoor did you view it in IE8?  If so what OS are you using

Comment: @Ben : IE8 (Emulated), Windows 7.

Comment: tried that and there is no problem for IE7,IE8,IE9 (emulated) and IE tester on win7

Comment: Wtf I'm using IE Tester on Windows 7 and it's throwing me off .. ><

Comment: @JanDvorak what does that do?  I'm using IE Tester for this, either way that did nothing.

Comment: @Ben Did you try hard-reload?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes as well as empty the cache, to no prevail!  I'm starting to think this is an issue only on my machine?

Comment: @Ben try to see what happens on the wire. Fiddler2 is a good tool, Wireshark as well if you're desperate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21826/discussion-between-ben-and-jan-dvorak)

Comment: Does this image has some transparency?

Comment: the .png does have transparency but not in the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker helped me figure this out.  I had to set the width and height of the DIV to be the same as the image size within it.  The browser was ignoring the div all together.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I add this styles inline and works:

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative !important;">
<!-- [...] -->
<div id="building" style="position: absolute !important; margin: 0px; width: 626px !important; float: none !important; height: 110px !important; right: 0px !important;">
```

[image]

Comment: Was it not displaying the building image before you applied the inline css?

Comment: The problem is not the image, is the <div id="building">, which is badly positioned and hidden.

Comment: Ah I see that you also included a width and height in your inline, thanks for the help @karacas